# Why is the output the same even though I enter differnt values?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a script to make life a little easier.. Let's say I input 5, 5, 10, 10, 150 in this order in the script. Shouldn't the output be different then? In my terminal I get the exact same output as the first value I entered for them all..

```
PFX = input("What's the customer prefix: ")
EXTSNAT = input("Enter the number of external SNAT addresses needed: ")
EXTVIP = input("How many addresses for public VIPs are needed: ")
INTSNAT = input("Enter the number of internal SNAT addresses needed: ")
INTVIP = input("Enter the number of internal VIP addresses needed: ")
PLATFORM_POOL = input("How many usable IPs should be allocated to platform pool: ")

list_to_check = [
     [EXTSNAT, "External SNAT"], 
     [EXTVIP, "External VIP"], 
     [INTSNAT, "Internal SNAT"], 
     [INTVIP, "Internal VIP"], 
     [PLATFORM_POOL, "Platform Pool"]
     ]

def address_blocks(list):
    value_0 = "/31"
    value_1 = "/30"
    value_2 = "/29"
    value_3 = "/28"
    value_4 = "/27"
    value_5 = "/26"
    value_6 = "/25"
    value_7 = "/24"

    for e in list:
        if int(e[0]) <= 2:
            print(f"{e[1]}: Use {value_0}")
        elif int(e[0]) >= 3:
             print(f"{e[1]}: Use {value_1}")
        elif int(e[0]) >= 5:
             print(f"{e[1]}: Use {value_2}")
        elif int(e[0]) >= 9:
             print(f"{e[1]}: Use {value_3}")
        elif int(e[0]) >= 17:
             print(f"{e[1]}: Use {value_4}")
        elif int(e[0]) >= 33:
             print(f"{e[1]}: Use {value_5}")
        elif int(e[0]) >= 65:
             print(f"{e[1]}: Use {value_6}")
        elif int(e[0]) >= 129:
             print(f"{e[1]}: Use {value_7}")
address_blocks(list_to_check)
```

Tried what I wrote over here.

Comment: I think your `elif int(e[0]) >= 3:` line will catch all the input values you show. Did you mean to have a `<=` comparison for all your conditions?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that what you want is this:

```
for e in list:
    if int(e[0]) <= 2:
        print(f"{e[1]}: Use {value_0}")
    elif int(e[0]) < 5:
         print(f"{e[1]}: Use {value_1}")
    elif int(e[0]) < 9:
         print(f"{e[1]}: Use {value_2}")
    elif int(e[0]) < 17:
         print(f"{e[1]}: Use {value_3}")
    elif int(e[0]) < 33:
         print(f"{e[1]}: Use {value_4}")
    elif int(e[0]) < 65:
         print(f"{e[1]}: Use {value_5}")
    elif int(e[0]) < 129:
         print(f"{e[1]}: Use {value_6}")
    elif int(e[0]) >= 129:
         print(f"{e[1]}: Use {value_7}")
```

The issue was with the range definitions inside the elif conditions. With your version `e[0] <= 2` and `e[0] >= 3` handle the whole integer space. There would be only 2 possible outcomes either use `value_0` when less or equal to 2 or use `value_1` when greater or equal than 3.

**EDIT:** Got rid of repeated comparisons as suggested by @quamrana

Comment: With these chained `if/elif` you only need a single `<` or `<=` since in each `elif` the other comparison is handled by the previous comparison. (It would be especially so if the numbers were `float`s).